# no response when using HttpURLConnection on android 5.0.2 (assus ZenPad 8.0 z380KL)

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm facing issues on getting a response from an asp.net webservice on android 5.0.2 assus zenpad 8 tablet over mobile data only.

Everything seams to work ok till ws start to exceed 50s/60s in delaying the response.

Other tablets and phones models seams to work and till now I have no idea what causing this kind of behaviour.

```
public String test(int delayResponse) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.1.10/Test.asmx");

        String requestMessage = getRequest(delayResponse);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        Log.i("ReadTimeout", Integer.toString(connection.getReadTimeout()));
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8;");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/TestConectivity");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(requestMessage.getBytes().length));

        connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        connection.setReadTimeout((delayResponse + 10)*1000);

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(requestMessage);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        if ( connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                StringBuilder sbResponse = new StringBuilder();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(stream ); 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader);
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sbResponse.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
                isReader.close();
                stream.close();
                return sbResponse.toString();
        }
        else {
            return Integer.toString(connection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage() + e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

private String getRequest(int delayResponse) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    sb.append("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
    sb.append("<soap:Body>");
    sb.append("<TestConectivity xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">");
    sb.append("<delayResponse>"+Integer.toString(delayResponse)+"</delayResponse>");
    sb.append("</TestConectivity>");
    sb.append("</soap:Body>");
    sb.append("</soap:Envelope>");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And this is the snippet of ws code

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Test
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Test : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string TestConectivity(int delayResponse)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delayResponse * 1000);
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: try using okhttp (https://github.com/square/okhttp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that some gsm carriers (Vodafone in my case) have a connection timeout through public APN... think that their network specialists feel the need to optimize their 4G and I'm feeling gladly that their competition it doesn't